# QML switch themes based on one on runtime

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'd like to have a control switching **light** and **dark** themes in my Qt project on runtime.

I need both themes to be based on `Material` style.

According to the documentation, I know that I can modify my style properties in `qtquickcontrols2.conf` file what could lead to sth like this:

```
[Controls]
Style=Material

[Material]
Accent=#2331aa
Primary=#926ec4
Variant=Dense
Foreground=#233232
Background=#F5F1FD
```

But what if I need to have both `Material.Light` **and** `Material.Dark` styles customized and switchable?

Could someone provide a minimalist working example of how to do that?